# Multiple UIViews with TableViews inside a ScrollView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I'm trying to create something like the Google Play Newsstand application (https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/google-play-newsstand/id459182288?mt=8).

Basically, I want to have multiple tableviews inside a scrollview that scrolls horizontally with paging enabled.
I currently have a UIViewController with a scrollview inside it. I am trying to load multiple tableviews inside this scrollview. The tableview is placed inside a UIView.
What I am doing currently is, iterating through the number of tableviews I need to swipe through (user defined) and creating an instance of the UIView class that has the tableview contained in it. This is causing a EXC_BAD_ACCESS which, with NSZombies enabled shows that the the dataSource is trying to access a deallocated object.

What should I do? I have been stuck on this since Friday. Should I, instead of creating an instance of the UIView class containing a tableview, directly create an instance of a TableView class?

I hope I have explained this well. Please let me know if something seems confusing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please, I have been frustratingly stuck on this.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: what the error u faced....bro

Comment: This is the message I get from NSZombie:
-[UIViewClassName tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x17102ac0

Comment: can you show your property on your view controller

Comment: The ViewController has a scrollView. The UIView has a tableView. Hope that's what you're asking.

Comment: it will occur  sometimes like , your tableview as an weak or your array released the memory ,